ReleaseInstance is not deleting the object instantiated from an Addressable
I have this simple script, which is working perfectly when I press I and it instantiates an addressable game object. But I am not sure why it is not deleting it when I press D. I confirmed that on press, the log is showing. I have checked in the build too.
public class LoadAddressable : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    AssetReferenceGameObject _vegetatoin;
    GameObject _instanceInstantaited;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
        {
            // _vegetatoin.InstantiateAsync();
            //_vegetatoin.LoadAssetAsync().Completed += OnAddressableLoaded;
            _vegetatoin.InstantiateAsync().Completed += OnAddressableLoaded;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            Debug.Log("deleting");
            _vegetatoin.ReleaseInstance(_instanceInstantaited);
        }
    }

    private void OnAddressableLoaded(AsyncOperationHandle<GameObject> handle)
    {
        if(handle.Status == AsyncOperationStatus.Succeeded)
        {
            _instanceInstantaited=  Instantiate(handle.Result);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Loading asset failed");
        }
    }
}

I am using ReleaseInstance and its documentation said that it destroys the object.
Edit: As @DMGregory helped in the comment. I have this full script which attached to an object. And I have assigned reference in the inspector of the object that I want to instantiate.
public class LoadAddressable : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    AssetReferenceGameObject _vegetatoin;
    GameObject _instanceInstantaited;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
        {
            // _vegetatoin.InstantiateAsync();
            //_vegetatoin.LoadAssetAsync().Completed += OnAddressableLoaded;
            _vegetatoin.InstantiateAsync().Completed += OnAddressableLoaded;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            Debug.Log("deteling");
            _vegetatoin.ReleaseInstance(_instanceInstantaited);
            if (_instanceInstantaited)
            {
                Debug.Log("still not null");
                Destroy(_instanceInstantaited);
                if (_instanceInstantaited)
                {
                    Debug.Log("still not null inner");
                    Destroy(_instanceInstantaited);
                }
            }
            
            Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();
        }
    }

    private void OnAddressableLoaded(AsyncOperationHandle<GameObject> handle)
    {
        if(handle.Status == AsyncOperationStatus.Succeeded)
        {
            _instanceInstantaited=  handle.Result;
            //_instanceInstantaited = Instantiate(handle.Result);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Loading asset failed");
        }
    }
}

Despite deleting the object, the memory is not released. And if I frequently do instantiate/delete, the memory starts incrementing but doesn't release. Yeah it does release about 10 MB. But actually it should release about 75 MB.
Here is my simple scene setup:


If looks to me like you're instantiating two copies of the object: one with InstantiateAsync() and one with Instantiate() in OnAddressableLoaded, but you only attempt to release/destroy one copy.

Oh! Silly mistake! Thanks for the help on success i just need to assign the reference not to instantiate it. But it not releasing the memory. Only sometime it get release but not all the time or most of the time.

Want to edit your question to show your corrected code and focus on your current issue? Are you sure you don't have any other instances of the asset still in the scene that might be holding onto that memory? Or variables pointing to them that you have not set to null?

Just to make sure, you only use I once for every D? You store the reference for every created object in the same variable, so if you create 2, you only know about one when you try to delete it

@Zibelas yes i only used it once. Let me check it again. with more bool so that it only work 1 time.

@Zibelas yes i can confirmed. i have added additional bool so that I and D should only work single time. Still the same problem.
